# Colour a polygon depending on the number containing of point feature

Tags: qgis, polygon, count

I have 2 different shape files, polygon and points.I am using QGIS 2.14 as a software. The points are distributed inside of the different polygon shapes. I try to do a categorized map using different colours depending of the number of points inside each polygon:

[image]

Comment: I use the tool points in polygon and then use the graduated style to show different colours, but is any other way to do it?

Comment: Please edit your question and tags to give information about software !

Answer (score 1):

Run the Join Attributes by Location tool on the polygon and point layer ([see this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html)).  This will give you an option to get the sum count of points within each polygon.  After you have that you may setup your rendering based on the new sum field in the new polygon layer.